# How to get the height of BB[α] tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, proof-of-correctness

In wikipedia about BB[α] tree: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight-balanced_tree
the height h <= log(1/(1-α))N(base is 1/(1-α)).

I cannot figure out how they derive this conclusion.

From the property, we can know that for any node, the weight of the parent v is at least a factor of 1/(1-α) larger than the weight of v, if the tree height is h, then we can know the root weight is (1/(1-α))^h, which are number of leaf nodes

Considering internal nodes, it's 2^0 + 2^1 + ... + 2^(h-2) + # of leaf nodes <= N, N is the total number of nodes

However, my derivation cannot get the conclusion in wikipedia, anyone can correct my mistake? Thanks

Comment: You should probably post this at http://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead of here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prove it like this.

The weight of a child node is bound to be larger than alpha times its parent.
Hence the parent weight is at least 1/(1-a) the child weight (on account of alpha being less than 0.5 for sure and the interval for the child to parent ratio given as alpha to 1-alpha.

So, if we have some height h the parent weight must be at least (1/1-a)^h by going from the deepest child to the parent.

So w=n >= (1/(1-α))^h

h <= log_{1/(1-α)}(n) ( choosing a different approach to indicating the base :D )